# YA Horror Series from the 80's?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

There was a hard bound horror series I enjoyed around 1986 or 1987. The books may have been published well before then but I enjoyed them.

The only piece I can remember is there is a pretty new girl at school that everyone likes but she creeps out another girl for some reason. Then at a bonfire or picnic the new girl says she needs hair from everyone but it turns out she some sort of demon or witch and really is out to get the girl that suspects her.

That's all I can remember. It's been driving me nuts.

Comment: Could it by any chance have been the *Witch* series (*Witch's Sister*, *Witch Water*, etc)?

Comment: @Jonah -- Good books, but I doubt they are the ones... Mrs. Tuggle was the primary antagonist (a traditional 'little old lady' type witch), with Lynn's sister, best friend, mother and little brother, being secondary (coming under Mrs. Tuggle's influence) in the first four books, but I can't say for sure about the last two; never had a chance to read them.

Comment: I don't think that was it. It was a series of horror stories. They were all different. At least I think they were. It was a long time ago.